# How do i use list as variable in regexp in Python

Tags: python, regex, list

How do i use list variable in regexp?
The problem is here:

```
re.search(re.compile(''.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, kand))), corpus.raw(fileid)))
```

error is

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

simple re.search works well, but i need list as first attribute in re.search:

```
for fileid in corpus.fileids():
    if re.search(r'[Чч]естны[й|м|ого].труд(а|ом)', corpus.raw(fileid)):
        dict_features[fileid]['samoprezentacia'] = 1
    else:
        dict_features[fileid]['samoprezentacia'] = 0

if re.search(re.compile('\b(?:%s)\b'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, kand))), corpus.raw(fileid))):
    dict_features[fileid]['up'] = 1
else:
    dict_features[fileid]['up'] = 0
```

return dict_features

by the way kand is list:

```
kand = [line.strip() for line in open('kand.txt', encoding="utf8")]
```

in output kand is  `['apple', 'banana', 'peach', 'plum', 'pineapple', 'kiwi']`

Edit: i am using Python 3.3.2 with WinPython on Windows 7
full errors stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Python/NLTK packages/agit_classify.py", line 59, in <module>
    print (regexp_features(agit_corpus))
  File "F:/Python/NLTK packages/agit_classify.py", line 53, in regexp_features
    if re.search(re.compile(r'\b(?:{0})\b'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, kandidats_all))), corpus.raw(fileid))):
  File "F:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.2.0\python-3.3.2\lib\re.py", line 214, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "F:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.2.0\python-3.3.2\lib\re.py", line 281, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "F:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.2.0\python-3.3.2\lib\sre_compile.py", line 494, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "F:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.2.0\python-3.3.2\lib\sre_parse.py", line 748, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, 0)
  File "F:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.2.0\python-3.3.2\lib\sre_parse.py", line 360, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state))
  File "F:\WinPython-32bit-3.3.2.0\python-3.3.2\lib\sre_parse.py", line 453, in _parse
    if state.flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: What are you expecting `''.format` to do?

Comment: Why would you ever do `re.search(re.compile(…))`? Just passing the regexp pattern string to `re.search` does the exact same thing. Or, if you _need_ to compile the regexps explicitly (e.g., performance, because you're going to use them repeatedly, or just to refactor your code), just use the `search` method on the compiled regexp.

Comment: i assume format list as apple|banana|peach  - i copied this from another answer on stackoverflow

Comment: Also, I can't see how you could ever get that error from that line of code. Can you give us the complete traceback, and the actual line of code it refers to?

Comment: experimented now and realized that this works, but not sure it right or pythonic:  re.search(re.compile('\b(?:%s)\b' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, kandidats_all))), corpus.raw(fileid))

Comment: @abarnert added in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting the actual exception is mismatched parentheses. Let's break it up to make it clearer:

```
re.search(
    re.compile(
        ''.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, kand))), 
        corpus.raw(fileid)))
```

In other words, you're passing a string, `corpus.raw(fileid)`, as the second argument to [`re.compile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile), not as the second argument to `re.search`.

In other words, you're trying to use it as the `flags` value, which is supposed to be an integer. When `re.compile` tries to use the `&` operator on your string to test each flag bit, it raises a `TypeError`.

And if you got past this error, the `re.search` would itself raise a `TypeError` because you're only passing it one argument rather than two.

This is exactly why you shouldn't write overly-complicated expressions. They're very painful to debug. If you'd written this in separate steps, it would be obvious:

```
escaped_kand = map(re.escape, kand)
alternation = '|'.join(escaped_kand)
whatever_this_was_supposed_to_do = ''.format(alternation)
regexpr = re.compile(whatever_this_was_supposed_to_do, corpus.raw(fileid))
re.search(regexpr)
```

This would also make it obvious that half the work you're doing isn't needed in the first place.

First, [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) takes a pattern, not a compiled regexpr. If it happens to work with a compiled regexpr, that's just an accident. So, that whole part of the expression is useless. Just pass the pattern itself.

Or, if you have a good reason to compile the regexpr, as [`re.compile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile) explains, the result regular expression object "can be used for matching using its `match()` and `search()` methods". So use the compiled object's `search` method, not the top-level `re.search` function.

Second, I don't know what you expected `''.format(anything)` to do, but it can't possibly return anything but `''`.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing old and [new string formatting rules](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). Also, you need to use raw strings with a regex, or `\b` will mean `backspace`, not [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```
'\b(?:%s)\b'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, kand)))
```

should be

```
r'\b(?:{0})\b'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, kand)))
```

Furthermore, be aware that `\b` only works if your "words" start and end with alphanumeric characters (or `_`).

Comment: experimented now and realized that this works, but not sure it right or pythonic:  re.search(re.compile('\b(?:%s)\b' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, kandidats_all))), corpus.raw(fileid))

Comment: why not... `re.compile('\b(?:%s)\b' + '|'.join(map(re.escape, kandidats_all))).search(kandidats_all)`, then you're calling search from the compiled regex object